# Ubuntu not booting, recovery mode not loading

Tags: multi-boot, ubuntu-11.10

I have a dual-boot Ubuntu 11.10 and Windows 7 machine setup and last night I had to force shutdown Ubuntu during updates because it wasn't responding. Since then, Ubuntu will not boot up, only flashing a blank lit screen for a split second every couple of seconds. Booting in recovery mode does not help either, as it doesn't load at all. If anyone can help me diagnose what's wrong and figure out what to do, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Boot a minimal Linux LiveCD, such as the [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/) minimal install CD and run the appropriate **fsck** on your partition(s).

Comment: Thanks, but actually I just resolved this myself.. -_- I managed to boot into command line mode from the recovery mode (via Ctrl-Alt-F1), and did a `sudo apt-get install` as well as a `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, and it finished the updates that I aborted. Then I rebooted and it worked after that. Sorry, but thanks for your help anyways! I'm sure it'll come in handy for someone else looking to resolve a similar issue!